# R script to determine the titre value from any given sample from PCR run

Tags: r

| avg_sample | titr_value |
| --- | --- |
| 15.15 | 700000 |
| 16.75 | 430000 |
| 17.65 | 70000 |
| 19.3 | 43000 |
| 21.85 | 7000 |
| 22.85 | 4300 |
| 24.475 | 700 |
| 26.57 | 430 |
| 27.505 | 70 |
| 29.65 | 43 |
| 29.6 | 7 |
| 29.735 | 4.3 |
| 30.5 | 3.5 |
| 31.545 | 2.1 |

Given the above sample PCR density with titre value. How do i determine a titre value of  a new sample density . My plan is to establish a PCR standard in the lab that will enable us to determine titre value of any sample once PCR sample density is known, then plot a relationship graph between the average sample and the titre value using ggplot. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A made a dataframe named vals to hold those values. I think you might want to come up with a compact formula for that relationship. It looks sort of hyperbolic but just plotting y=1/x doesn't really linearize it. I needed to plot y ~ log(1/x) to get a straight line.

```
plot(vals$avg_sample ~ log(1/vals$titr_value))
```

[image]

Since that looks acceptably linear you just enter the transformed values into a linear regression and get an equation for a line of best fit.

```
lm( avg_sample ~ log(1/titr_value) , data=vals)

Call:
lm(formula = avg_sample ~ log(1/titr_value), data = vals)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)  log(1/titr_value)  
           32.656              1.246  
 #-----

> png()
> plot(vals$avg_sample ~ log(1/vals$titr_value))
> abline( lm( avg_sample ~ log(1/titr_value) , data=vals))
> dev.off()
```

[image]

I'm sure the process can be done in ggplot but I'm kind of a base-graphics guy.

Comment: thank you for your contribution. My question is how can we determine a new  titre value of a known sample density from PCR run. e.g having a density of 11.3 from a PCR run, what should be its corresponding  titre value. We want to set up a standard in the lab. once we have a PCR of XYZ, we should also know the corresponding titre value.

Comment: You could invert the formula that you derived with the regression. Or you plot y = 1/x with og axes. Your choice. Depends on whether you want a graphical reference or plan to embed it in a R function.